# phpStorm losing keyboard input

Tags: 13.10, java, ibus, ide

Every now and again phpStorm will lose input from my keyboard. I can still click around, but it will not register any keys. Other windows are fine. It takes a phpStorm restart to bring them back. It seems to happen most when I Control+Tab between open tabs

I am running:
Ubuntu 13.10
phpStorm 7.1
JRE 1.7.0_51

Comment: This is still experienced in Ubuntu 14.04.3 phpStorm 9.0.2

Comment: phpStorm is a paid app.  Don't they support their software?  This isn't really anything to do with Ubuntu I don't think.

Comment: @Goddard this is not just phpStorm nor Ubuntu issue. It is X window/ Ibus problem with any Jetbrains product really.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should look at this bug here:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79312

It's exactly your issue, and it has a potential workaround:

```
sudo ibus restart
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sweet, fixes it for me and much quicker than a restart

Comment: Watch out latin keyboard people, it worked for me but made my keyboard switch to QWERTY. Had to input in a terminal the "setxkbmap fr" command to make it AZERTY again.

Comment: @STW but the problem still exists and it's keep loosing focus

Comment: @Gtx - yep, it's not a fix but it will regain keyboard input (at least for a while).  It's best to give feedback to Jetbrains so they'll hopefully work on a fix.

Comment: This worked for me to, but I always need to run that command again to regain my keyboard input later. Is there a way to trigger that command when the keyboard lose focus?

Comment: Seems like the correct issue for OP is actually this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Comment: root@myhost:~# sudo ibus restart
Keine Verbindung zu IBus.

Comment: With sudo I get "Can't connect to IBus."
Without sudo it works thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the correct issue/bug for OP is actually this: [IDEA-78860](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860)

This is not a Ubuntu version specific, but X Window / IBus problem and it is still happening in Ubuntu 14.04 with IBus < 1.5.11

**Option 1:**
Update IBus to [1.5.11 or higher](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/releases)
Check this answer on [how to update ibus on ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/a/735381/274549)

**Option 2:**
Official workaround, is to add following line to your ~/.profile

```
export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1
```

Remember you have to **restart your session** (logout) for this to take effect.

**Option 3:**
 
The most universal workaround is still `ibus restart`, but I think it is worth to quote the assignee of the issue:

> Restarting IBus isn't recommended (may crash the IDE later)

Yes, that may happen sooner or later. Also this resets your keyboard layout to default (mostly english). So you'd have change that back every time you restart ibus.

Another option is to disable ibus, but this really is not a solution for people who do not have US kb layout.

Answer (score 0):

i prevent this issue, by a changing "Keyboard input method system" (System settings > language support) from "IBus" to "none".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33684325/250814

Answer (score -1):

```
ibus restart && sleep 1 && ibus engine xkb:se::swe
```

worked for me

Comment: this makes your keyboard layout swedish. This should NOT be an answer for this case.

Comment: @igorsantos07 This restarts ibus and resets KB locale to swedish yes, but you can change it to whatever KB layout you have. Point is, restarting ibus will reset you KB layout to default, english mostly.

Answer (score -1):

you can try removing the `.idea` folder at the root of your project, then try *File → Invalidate cache and restart*.